# Find the position of any of a number of characters with an offset - php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to find the position of any of a number of characters, but need to be able to set a search offset.

This is precisely the functionality of `strpos()` but matching any of a number of characters rather than a single string/character.  If `strpos()` would accept an array of $needles it would be exactly what I need (assuming it returns the position of the earliest match in $haystack).

`strpbrk()` has exactly what's needed in terms of matching a set of characters, but this does not allow an offset so that I can move along the string after each successful match.

This seems an odd thing to be missing from the PHP string functions, is there something I am missing?

Here is a code summary:

> ```
>   while($pos=strpos($el->text(), '*_-!`' ,$el->position())!==FALSE){
>       $el->position($pos);
>
>        foreach ($HandlerTypes as $Type){
>           // Note: $el->position is modified within this function
>           $this->markSpan($Type, $el);
>        }
>    }
> ```

Where I'm looking for any of `*`, `_`, `-`, `!` or ` rather than the string of them.
Any marker might appear more than once in the string.

thanks.

Comment: Do you want match the same character if it occurs more then two times, don't you? Just some pseudocode an the excepted output would help answering your question.

Comment: providing a test case (and expected output) might help your cause.

Comment: In the user comments on this [php.net strpos page](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). There appears to be two functions that will help you out. Namely [this one](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#107678) and [this one](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#102773)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions to the rescue!

```
$s = 'skipbfoobarxarjar';
preg_match_all('~[bxj]~', $s, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 5);
print_r($m[0]);
```

Result:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => 8
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => x
        [1] => 11
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => j
        [1] => 14
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, preg_match also works in my scenario, turns out it also allows the setting of an offset to start further along the string.  @Dale Your links are also useful relating to this problem.